# How to safely & properly storing JWT token in Electron App

Tags: jwt, electron

I'm building an electron desktop app, and in the app it will call the remote API with JWT token. However, where should I persist this JWT token safely without the threats like XSS, CSRF, man in the middle attack etc... and cannot be accessible by other applications

I've tried using `node-keytar` package, which uses an encryption key derived from the user’s login.

But according to this issue(https://github.com/atom/node-keytar/issues/88), the credential(JWT in our scenario) can still be compromised if the user's environment got a malware installed.

The code of node-keytar is fairly easy, here's the add secret

```
keytar.addPassword('KeytarTest', 'AccountName', 'secret');
```

and here's the get secret

```
const secret = keytar.getPassword('KeytarTest', 'AccountName');
console.log(secret); // "supersecret"
```

I'm thinking about just storing JWT into the memory might be the safest way, but will require user to re-login and get JWT token everytime they reopen the electron desktop app.
Any suggestions or thoughts are welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In many use cases involving JWT, you would not need to necessarily do any additional encryption/obfuscation of the JWT before you send it to the API, because:

- When you send the JWT to the API, you would be doing so via SSL or HTTPS, which encrypts the entire payload.  This in theory would eliminate most chances of man-in-the-middle attacks.
- Even if someone managed to sniff your JWT token, they would lack the server's key which is required to unlock it.  Also, even if they managed to unlock the JWT, it would be almost impossible to alter its contents without also altering the checksum, which is contained within the JWT itself.  This eliminates the chance of injection attacks by inserting something into the JWT.

So in general, the JWT pattern is a way of pushing server side session state outside of the application.  And it does it in such a way that this state is protected from tampering on the outside.  If it *were* possible to easily tamper with a JWT on the outside, the entire pattern would fall apart.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response!!
but if they got the JWT token, they can just directly use that token to get access to certain api endpoint without tampering it
And also, assume that the client's OS is filled with malware, how do I safely keep the JWT token in the electron App when the user is not doing anything.(exclude the context of man in the middle attack)

Comment: @johnhckuo Your comment is now mentioning yet another potential problem with JWT, which is that if someone malicious gets a hold of it, they can steal your identity.  But, this problem is really no different than the risk that someone other than yourself could steal your passport or credit card.  It is simply a risk which can't be completely mitigated.  The only completely safe approach would be to require the user to enter his credentials with each and every action.  But, this is not practical, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but that is what the question is about. How and where to store the JWT to prevent chances of such identity theft.